# How to removed mini cart picture with the width and height

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I need to remove the width and height of the picture in mini-cart pages. I have checked about Magento developer document. I realize I can set up in view.xml to change the width and height, but here is the problem while I configure the width and the height in the view.xml the pic is stretched. I also checked about code (See below code). 
It's written by knockout js

```
    <a class="action showcart" title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('My Basket')) ?>" href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getShoppingCartUrl(); ?>"
   data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
    <span class="crat-icon">
        <span class="counter qty empty"
              data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false }, blockLoader: isLoading">
            <span class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
            <span class="counter-label">
            <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
                <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="text cart-title"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Your Cart'); ?></span>
    <span class="text" data-bind="html: getCartParam('subtotal')"></span>
</a>
```

Are any solutions that I can remove the width and height in the mini cart page?

Answer (score 1):

Please try with below path and change code :

**If you want to remove image than check with below path :**

`app/design/frontend/Themes/Yourtheme/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html`

if file not exist than copy from default Magento path than paste above path

default magento path : `vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\minicart\item\default.html`

**OR If you want resize than do with below step :**

> app\design\frontend\Themes\Yourtheme\etc\view.xml

```
<image id="mini_cart_product_thumbnail" type="thumbnail">
    <width>75</width>
    <height>75</height>
</image>
```

to replace with :

```
<image id="mini_cart_product_thumbnail" type="small_image">
    <width>75</width>
    <height>75</height>
</image>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solutions!!! Since the mini cart pic is distorted after I setting view.xml width and height. So it seems I have to remove the width and height in the Html file which is controlled by knockout js, but here is the problem that even though I console.log the data,  
 I still have no idea about how to remove the width and height before render.